# UWP NavigationView: How to resize the width?

Tags: c#, uwp, resize, width, navigationview

I want to resize the width of the NavigationView. Windows Mail provides this resizeable feature. I cannot find an option to enable it. Example GIF:

[Resizing NavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4a0I.gif)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think NavigationView provides this feature itself.
Maybe you can try to adjust the width by `OpenPaneLenght` and use a bar like `GridSplitter`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/gridsplitter
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.openpanelength#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_OpenPaneLength